# Play Framework 2 and multiple slf4j bindings

Tags: logging, binding, playframework, log4j, slf4j

When starting my Play application I have a warning regarding multiple slf4j bindings:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/play-2.2.1/repository/local/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/jars/logback-classic.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/play-2.2.1/repository/cache/org.apache/phoenix/jars/phoenix-2.2.3-incubating-client.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

I have tried to exclude almost everything from the second jar, but no success.

```
"org.apache" % "phoenix" % "2.2.3-incubating-client"
   exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api")
   exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j")
   exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
   exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-impl")
   exclude("org.apache.logging.log4j", "log4j-slf4j-impl")
   exclude("log4j", "log4j"),
```

For now I get logs only from the Play controllers, none from the inner jars. How do I know what to exclude? Is there a way (or need) to exclude the first binding (from a Play local repository jar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fix has been merged on master about that: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3206